# How to use str_replace for multiple replacements from a same string?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this code:

```
$fincontent=str_replace("href=\"index.php?", "href=\"index.php?s=blog&", $precontent);
$content=str_replace("src=\"images/", "src=\"../../blog/images/", $fincontent);
```

it works but I feel like there must be a shorthand so I tried this:

```
str_replace(array('href=\"index.php?', 'href=\"index.php?s=blog&'), array('src=\"images/', 'src=\"../../blog/images/'), $precontent);
```

but it only messed it all up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this php? please tag it so. Can you add a complete example (define `$precontent`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) function in PHP.

```
$replace = [
  "href=\"index.php?" => "href=\"index.php?s=blog&",
  "src=\"images/" => "src=\"../../blog/images/"
];

$content = strtr($precontent, $replace);
```

Comment: are you sure about this? I got this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: That could be from array short syntax perhaps?  This functionality was introduced in php 5.4.  Otherwise, I'm not sure. I copied and pasted this exactly into a script and ran it again and I did not receive that error you shared.  That being said - if you're using an older version of PHP, `$replace` should be a standard array - so just say `$replace = array(["href.....`

Comment: Actually it worked by modifying it like this: `$replace = array("href=\"index.php?" => "href=\"index.php?s=blog&",`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way,

```
$content=str_replace("src=\"images/", "src=\"../../blog/images/", str_replace("href=\"index.php?", "href=\"index.php?s=blog&", $precontent));
```